# php Entry transformation

Tags: php, transformation

I have a database with more than 20000 rows.

A column has this expression:

```
<td align="left" valign="top"><input name="mail" type="hidden" id="mail" value="mail@domain.com," /></td>
```

And I want to retrieve only the email address; how can I do that using php?

Comment: Your DB column has that HTML in it?

Comment: Can you guarantee the format above?  Or, is it more freeform?  If you can guarantee it, you should be able to grab that e-mail address with RegEx.  If it varies, or is more complicated, I suggest a DOM parser.

Comment: this is the exacte expression in each column only the email adress which is different

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to remove the extra text before and after the email value:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING  '," /></td>'
            FROM TRIM(LEADING '<td align="left" valign="top"><input name="mail" type="hidden" id="mail" value="'
            FROM your_field)) AS email
FROM your_table;
```

It will work because you confirmed that in a comment `this is the exacte expression in each column only the email adress which is different`.

Using a MySQL-only solution will be faster than using MySQL to retrieve the data, and PHP to extract the emails. It also enables you to write a query to easily and quickly save the emails in another column or table.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is exactly the same in all rows, you can actually do this in SQL like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        field_name,
        '<td align="left" valign="top"><input name="mail" type="hidden" id="mail" value="',\
        ''
    ),
    '" /></td>',
    ''
) as email
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as this format is completely static, you can get away with a pretty sloppy regex, as demonstrated below:

```
$ cat emailreg.php
<?php
$html = '<td align="left" valign="top"><input name="mail" type="hidden" id="mail" value="mail@domain.com," /></td>';
if(preg_match('@value="(?P<email>[^",]+),"@', $html, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches['email']);
}
$ php emailreg.php
string(15) "mail@domain.com"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows, assuming $column contains your column value as shown below:

```
$column='<td align="left" valign="top"><input name="mail" type="hidden" id="mail" value="mail@domain.com," /></td>' ;
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $column );
echo $xml->input[0]['value'] . "\n" ;
```

Example of the otput:

```
mail@domain.com,
```

It will display your email.
Of course this good when you have already `$column`. In case you want to process whole query like that, please do as others suggest, processing it while querying for it will be much faster.

In case you like it here a function you could use:

```
function getmail( $column )
{
    return simplexml_load_string( $column )->input[0]['value'] ;
}
```

and usage:

```
echo getmail( '<td align="left" valign="top"><input name="mail" type="hidden" id="mail" value="mail@domain.com," /></td>' ) ;
```

Have fun.